# Run batch file code from java code

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to execute a batch file code from java button click. Also I don't want any command prompt window to be shown all from java code.

I have a code :-

```
C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin>dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/mobile-phone/m
obilePhone.xyz --format=pdf --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Use
rs/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt
```

So I want above code to be run from batch command with  **C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin>** as the parent directory.

Also I want to update **--input** file path whenever I will choose new file from JFileChooser.

I did this from the java code on button click transform:-

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/mobile-phone/mobilePhone.xyz --format=pdf --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Users/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process=pb.start();
```

and getting IOException error.

I get stuck over here for long time , where am I going wrong.

**EDIT :- error**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/mobile-phone/m
obilePhone.xyz --format=pdf --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Use
rs/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Kindly post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: " getting IOException error" - it would be helpful to let us know _which_ error you get (e.g. message, stacktrace etc.)

Comment: @Azeem I have added the exception in EDIT

Comment: @Thomas I have added in Edit , please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String inputFile = ...;
String outputFile = ...;
String logFile = ...;

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "dita",
        "--input=" + inputFile,
        "--format=pdf",
        "--output=" + outputFile,
        "--logfile=" + logFile)
    .directory(new File("C:\\xyz-3.1.1\\bin"))
    //.inheritIO();
    .redirectErrorStream(true);

Process process = pb.start();
```

This shows the following points:

1. The command is separated from the arguments
2. The argument values can be determined at runtime
3. The command's default directory (`C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin`) is set before starting the process
4. Consider using `inheritIO()` instead of `redirectErrorStream()` if you want the process's output to appear as part of your Java application's output.

Comment: Its throwing error `java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid`

Comment: @WhoAmI check you're using the correct directory name. If you can't see the problem, show me the exact call you make to `directory(...)`.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am using the same directory call. I can do it successfully manually by command prompt.

Comment: Well, that error message means that the directory name you supplied was not a valid directory. Perhaps you used the name of a regular file instead of a directory, or the name contained an illegal character such as "`>`".

Comment: It is like in `C:` i have `xyz-3.1.1` folder inside that it is `bin` folder. So when I have set the path `C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin` , I will call the command which is `dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/ditamaps/mobile-phone/mobilePhone.ditamap --format=html5 --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Users/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt` . I don't think there is some illegal characters

Comment: Did you use a double backslash in your Java string? You need `"\\"` to denote a single backslash.

Comment: ok after doing this I am getting new error for `dita`  .. `The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @WhoAmI if the command `dita` is in fact a batch file (type `where dita` and see if it says for example `C:\path\to\bin\dita.bat` or `dita.cmd`), then you'll have to add the file extension to `ProcessBuilder` (i.e. `"dita.bat"` or `"dita.cmd"` as the first argument). If you just use `"dita"` it assumes it's a binary executable, `dita.exe`.

Comment: Yes `dita` is a batch file , I did both `"dita.bat"` or `"dita.cmd"` , it is throwing error `The system cannot find the file specified`. Though manually `C:\path\to\bin>dita.bat .. ..` is working

Comment: Hmm. A bit puzzled, but try `"C:\\path\\to\\bin\\dita.bat"` instead of `"dita.bat"`.

Comment: By the way, which version of the JDK are you using? I'm using javac 1.8.0_181 (64-bit) and it works, but I think earlier versions couldn't directly execute batch files but instead you had to run the Command Processor (cmd.exe) to run the batch file. So you might try `"cmd.exe", "/c", "dita", "--input=..." etc`.

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_121(64bit) . Let me try.

Answer (score 3):

As the `Error` mentioned, it cannot locate the **command** because the whole string will be treated as the **command** by `ProcessBuilder`.

Try to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` directly, but you have to ensure the command `dita` can be found.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin>dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/mobile-phone/mobilePhone.xyz --format=pdf --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Users/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt");
process.waitFor();
int exitCode = process.exitValue();
System.out.println(IoHelper.output(process.getInputStream())); // handle the output;
```

Before JDK 5.0, the only way to start a process and execute it, was to use the exec() method of the java.lang.Runtime class after which ProcessBuilder can be used to help create operating system processes.

The major improvement being that, it also acts as a **holder** for all those attributes that influence the process. And this is how it should be used:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
```

P.S. Actually `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` can also be used with `String...` as:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"curl", "-v", "--cookie", tokenString, urlString});
```

My personal preference:

1. If you have to configure the environment for the command: to control the `working directory` or `environment variables` and also you want to execute the commands several times, you'd better use it since the `ProcessBuilder` will hold the settings and what you need to do is just `processBuilder.start()` to create another process with the same settings;
2. If you want to execute a whole long string command as you mentioned, you'd better just use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` since you can just execute it right there without any bothering of the parameter format.

Comment: yes , that's correct , I am doing some mistake on the command . That's what my question is how can I write the command, so that I can execute it in java `C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin>dita --input=C:/Users/india/Desktop/mobile-phone/m
obilePhone.xyz --format=pdf --output=C:/Users/india/Desktop --logfile=C:/Use
rs/india/Desktop/dofhdif.txt` rather than doing separately in batch .

Comment: Your first point is making sense. Since I don't know much about batch scripting , how will I achieve this in my case.

Comment: What exactly is `dita` in your **command**? A script file name?

Comment: If so, you can just directly use `exec` to execute it directly. If not, then what's the error?

Comment: I have to be in this directory `C:\xyz-3.1.1\bin>` to execute the command.

Comment: @whoami I just updated the answer, perhaps you should add the `absolute` path for the command. Or you can add this command in `classpath` to make sure the jvm can locate it.

Comment: Thanks , I am looking to it , also I how can I modify my `--input` file path every time when choosing file from JFileChooser?

Comment: @WhoAmI Using string concatenation? Not quite sure what you are implying? Or it’s another question related to JFileChooser?

Comment: Yes , I tried with concatenation, but not getting attached. I asked this within this question only.

Comment: @WhoAmI Do remember the white spaces among the arguments and perhaps you can try to store it to a local variable and print it out to check it.